# NinjectHttpApplication Controller Event Registration

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, events, ninject

I'm using MVC NinjectHttpApplication.  I have a number of controllers that inherit from a base class (ControllerBase).  The base class exposes an event.  I want to register a common event handler with each concrete controller instance when Ninject initializes the controller.  Something like:

```
var eventHandler = new EventHandlingObject();

foreach (var controller in kernel.GetAll<ControllerBase>())
{
   controller.SomeEvent += eventHandler.HandlingMethod;
}
```

Are there any hooks into the StandardKernel that will allow me to intercept the controller instantiation and wire up the event?  If no, is there any way to retrieve all of the controllers that were registered in the call to

```
kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

so that I can iterate through them and register the event on each?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are seriously misunderstanding how controllers work. Getting all controllers and registering an event on them makes absolutely no sense because a new instance is created for each request.

What you can do is to add an activation action (`OnActivation(....)`). But what's probably even easier is to invert the control and change from an event to injecting the event handling object to your controllers and call the event handling method on them.

Comment: Can't argue with the misunderstanding part.  My original implementation injected a number of dependencies that were only used by the base controller, requiring the inheriting controllers to implement identical constructors.  I'll give it another go using either an aggregate constructor or property injection.